# asp.net webservice security without changing client side

Tags: asp.net, web-services, delphi, webservice-client

we need to protect our webservices with SSL (https) or any other security mechanism. Our problem is that current clients (delphi exe's) have references to our http webservices fixed in code and can not change that code.

I've tried to implement URL redirection rule from http to https but that didn't work because of the "hand shake"...Changing client to use https reference did work but saddly we can not do that for every client.

I know this question is in contradiction with encription theories but i'll fire this question anyway if anyone has any type of suggestion/idea to at least make connection or data transfer more secured (either with or without SSL protocol) without changing client side.

Thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some kind of transparent TCP tunneling software/hardware on the clients, so the encryption occurs without the delphi clients noticing it.

My Google search using "transparent encrypted tunneling" keywords got [this vendor](http://www.ssh.com/) of such solutions. There's must other vendors with similar solutions.

This is really an networking question.

PS.: hardcoding the URL is the real problem here. After the tunneling palliative is done, change that because this really will cause more headaches in future.

Comment: Very usefull answer as our company is growing really fast and need to upgrade security as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The client will be connecting over a port (non SSL) that will need to remain. What you could possibly do is that if you allow access both http and https you could possibly only allow http from specific IP addresses if you know them? its still not secure, but least you know where the calls are coming from and can do something about that?

Comment: This idea could be implemented for some most critical security features. WS could return a message to client to register his IP through some web form on our site...Thanks for the idea!